# Django custom filter look up template variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a custom template filter in Django, can I access the other template variable inside the template filter.

```
{{lookup_dict}}

{% for a in my_list %}
    {{a|my_filter:1}}
{% endfor %}

@register.filter
def my_filter(obj, val):
    # I need to access "lookup_dict" here 
    return ...
```

Comment: I imagine the answer is either no, or yes with incredible difficulty. If you are running into many problems like this I suggest entertaining the idea of looking into Jinja2 templating, which is far more flexible with args and kwargs.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to change your tag into a template tag instead of a filter - filters are supposed to be atomic and independent of context. Something like this should work:

```
# takes_context allows you access to the outer template context
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True) 
def my_tag(context, obj, val):
    lookup_dict = context['lookup_obj']
    # Do something with lookup_dict, obj, and val
    # Return something that will be rendered in the template
    return ...
```

Then in your template:

```
{% for a in my_list %}
    {% my_tag a 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that this is now a tag (`{%`) instead of a variable (`{{`).